# What causes this 500 error while trying to load comments via AJAX in a Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have made a **[blogging application in Laravel 8](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/49)**.

On the single article view, I am displaying comments and comment replies.

There is an option to *load comments via AJAX*, on page scroll.

When the "infinite scroll" option is checked, the first 10 comments are present on page load, the rest are loaded via AJAX.

In `ArticlesController.php` I have:

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

  public function show( $slug ) {
    // Single article
    $article     = Article::firstWhere( 'slug', $slug );
    $old_article = Article::where( 'id', '<', $article->id )->orderBy( 'id', 'DESC' )->first();
    $new_article = Article::where( 'id', '>', $article->id )->orderBy( 'id', 'ASC' )->first();

    // Comments
    $commentsQuery  = $this->get_commentQuery( $article->id );
    $comments_count = $commentsQuery->count();

    // If infinite scroll, paginate comments (to be loaded one page per scroll),
    // Else show them all 

    if (boolval($this->is_infinitescroll)) {
      $comments = $commentsQuery->paginate($this->comments_per_page);
    } else {
      $comments = $commentsQuery->get();
    }

    return view( 'themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single',
                 array_merge( $this->data, [
                   'categories'        => $this->article_categories,
                   'article'           => $article,
                   'old_article'       => $old_article,
                   'new_article'       => $new_article,
                   'comments'          => $comments,
                   'comments_count'    => $comments_count,
                   'comments_per_page' => $this->comments_per_page,
                   'tagline'           => $article->title,
                   'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll
                 ] )
    );
  }

  /**
   * AJAX Call for Loading extra comments
   *
   * @param Request $request
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function get_comments_ajax( Request $request ) {
    if ( ! $request->ajax() ) {
      exit();
    }

    $more_comments_to_display = TRUE;

    $article_id  = $request->post( 'article_id' );
    $page_number = $request->post( 'page' );
    $offset      = $this->comments_per_page * $page_number;

    $data['comments'] = $this->get_commentQuery( $article_id, $this->comments_per_page, $offset )->get();
    $content          = '';
    if ( $data['comments']->count() ) {
      $content .= view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/partials/comments-list',
                array_merge( $data, [
                  'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll
                ])
      );
    } else {
      $more_comments_to_display = FALSE;
    }
    echo json_encode( [ 'html' => $content, 'page' => $page_number, 'more_comments_to_display' => $more_comments_to_display, 'article_id' => $article_id ] );
    exit();
  }

  /**
   * get_commentQuery
   *
   * @param int $article_id
   * @param int $limit
   * @param int $offset
   *
   * @return object
   */
  private function get_commentQuery( int $article_id, int $limit = 0, int $offset = 0 ): object {
    $commentQuery = Comment::where( [ 'article_id' => $article_id, 'approved' => 1 ] )
        ->orderBy( 'id', $this->comments_orderby_direction )
        ->with('replies', function($query){
             $query->where('approved', 1);
        });

    if ( $offset > 0 ) {
      $commentQuery = $commentQuery->offset( $offset );
    }
    if ( $limit > 0 ) {
      $commentQuery = $commentQuery->limit( $limit );
    }

    return $commentQuery;
  }
}
```

In `infinite-comments.js` I have:

```
/* Infinite comments
* ------------------------------------------------------ */
$(document).ready(function () {

    let flagMoreCommentsToDisplay = true;
    let flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = false;
    let domInfiniteScroll = $(".infinite-scroll");

    infiniteComments();

    function infiniteComments() {
        let page = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (flagCommentsBlockNewRequest === false) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - $('.s-footer').height()) {
                    if (flagMoreCommentsToDisplay) {
                        flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = true;
                        page++;
                        loadMoreData(page);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function loadMoreData(page) {
        let base_url = window.location.origin
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/load_comments',
            type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
            data: {'_token': token, 'page': page, 'article_id': article_id},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.ajax-load').show();
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            let commentHtml = data.html;
            flagMoreCommentsToDisplay = data.more_comments_to_display;
            if (flagMoreCommentsToDisplay) {
                if (commentHtml !== '') {
                    domInfiniteScroll.append(commentHtml);
                }
            }
            flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = false;
        })
        .fail(function () {
            flagCommentsBlockNewRequest = false;
        });
    }
});
```

In the blade file that displays the comments - `comments-list.blade.php`:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    @if (null == $comment->parent_id)
        <li class="depth-1 comment">
            <div class="comment__avatar">
              <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}" alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="comment__content">
                <div class="comment__info">
                    <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
                    <div class="comment__meta">
                        <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
                        @auth
                          <div class="comment__reply">
                              <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">Reply</a>
                          </div>
                        @endauth
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment__text">
                    <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            @auth
                @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')
            @endauth

            {{-- Comment replies --}}
            @if (count($comment->replies))
                <ul class="children">
                    @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
                        <li class="depth-2 comment">
                            <div class="comment__avatar">
                                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $reply->user->avatar) }}"
                                    alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}"
                                    width="50" height="50">
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment__content">
                                <div class="comment__info">
                                    <div class="comment__author">{{ $reply->user->first_name }}
                                        {{ $reply->user->last_name }}</div>
                                    <div class="comment__meta">
                                        <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($reply->created_at)) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__text">
                                    <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

#### The problem

On page scroll, loading more comments *fails with a 500 error*:

> POST https://larablog.com/load_comments 500 (Internal Server Error)

The content of `laravel.log` related to the error is in **[THIS](https://gist.github.com/Ajax30/e111546453f7bfc378c0027f1340b86d)** Github Gist.

#### Questions

1. What is my mistake?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: Check the error log to get the exception details. All that a 500 error tells you us that the program crashed in some way. More info is needed before anyone can help.

Comment: Check error log for Laravel. If there is no related log, check server (Apache/nginx) logs and php error logs.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei I have added the PHP error log too.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir That appears to be a partial error message; some is missing. You've showed us line #45 of a large stacktrace.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have added the entire today's error message in the logs.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Every stack trace in my logs has a line *above* the stacktrace with the actual error. For example, https://gist.github.com/ceejayoz/c55500b70d8dc0c33ec315146bf0ebf6. Please, please, please take a careful look at your logs; the cause of the error will be in there.

Comment: @ceejayoz There is the required *[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Ajax30/e111546453f7bfc378c0027f1340b86d)*.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir "Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Undefined variable: theme_directory" seems pretty clear. You haven't passed that variable to your view, so `@include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')` fails..

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't understand your comment.

Comment: You are using a variable in your view that you did not pass **to** the view. Your `return view()` call needs to send the `$theme_directory` value to the view.

Comment: @ceejayoz The `ArticlesController` extends the `FrontendController`, which contains the `$theme_directory` variable.

Comment: My suggestion is that try to check each line of code of "get_comments_ajax()" function starting from first line - it can be done by simply returning the request like "return $request" and look at the console from frontend, this is how I debug my codes, hope it helps

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Being defined in the controller doesn't make it controlled in the view. You have to **pass** it from the controller to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is: `Undefined variable: theme_directory` in `resources\views\themes\calvin\partials\comments-list.blade.php`

Your method `get_comments_ajax` uses view `comments-list` without `$theme_directory` variable.

Try to add `$this->theme_directory` and `$article` like in this code:

```
$article = Article::find((int)$article_id);

$content .= view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/partials/comments-list',
    array_merge( $data, [
        'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll,
        'theme_directory' => $this->theme_directory,
        'article' => $article
    ])
);
```

Comment: I have made the changes but there is still an errror: `Undefined variable: article (View: E:\wamp64\www\larablog\resources\views\themes\calvin\partials\comment-form.blade.php))`

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I have added code for `$article` in my post above.

Comment: Yes, I know. In fact `'article_id' => $article_id` is needed. And this in the view: `<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ isset($article->id) ? $article->id : $article_id }}">`. Thanks!